# Girar texto via CSS

Tags: css

Existe alguma forma de girar um texto, para ficar igual a imagem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisando, vi que tem o `transform: rotate(10deg);`, gostaria de saber se é funcional para o **IE8**, ou se já outra alternativa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade rotate não funciona em IE8

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Pra funcionar no IE8 tem uns esquemas usando filter, acho que esse tópico resolve teu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie

Comment: E para os outros navegadores, é o `rotate` mesmo?

Comment: Aham, os IEs antigos que são problemáticos, é sempre bom olhar nesse caniuse.com, ele mostra até os "Known issues" da propriedade que você quer usar.

Comment: Perfeito, acho que vou usar uma imagem mesmo, para não ter problemas.